# Only blur repeated image in background?

Tags: html, image, css, background-image

i have a div with a background image. the background image css is set as follows:

```
.resPic1 {
    background: url(../css/images/residentialpic1.jpeg) center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

What i want to know is if there is a way to *only* blur the **repeated** images (the repeated images that are outside the blue lines i've highlighted in my picture) any help is appreciated! [image]

Comment: Do you really need the background to be repeated?

Comment: ideally yeah, i removed the repeat but the container div seemed to be a little too empty for my liking.. and fitting the image to the div stretched it too much unfortunately @Swellar

Comment: Maybe add two background images, one blurred and one normal? You can center the second image and have the blurred one behind. Dont think you can do it with one image only.

Comment: Do you know the image dimensions? If so, you might be able to do it with `:before` and `:after`

Comment: if all else fails i may result to @Syfer alternative, seems reasonable. Michael, yeah i think i can make the dimensions static

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you've got a blurred version of your image, you can achieve it by applying multiple background-images on your element :

```css
body {
  /* place the blurred image below the normal one */
  background-image:
    url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg"),
    url("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/z3icpq9rkrf4rac/blurred_10px_mermaid.png?dl=0");

  /* repeat only the blurred one */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;

  background-position: center, center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And if you don't, a little `::before`+`::after` hack can do it too :

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  }
body::before, body::after{
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  }
/* the blurred image */
body::before{
  content: "";
  background-repeat: repeat;
  filter: blur(3px);
  }
/* the clear image */
body::after{
  content: "";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

A small workaround, using fixed heights and two different `div`s.. May not be recommended though..

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.blur-bg {
  height: 300px;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url('https://lh5.ggpht.com/6IV7BAcqjvjlbtYN27Dbh8-Khc5fEhJJOHxUYG7omxUoW_q8WDwqAeHvCWNwO7bTDg=h900');
  position: absolute;
  height: 299px;
  width: 100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  background-image: url('https://lh5.ggpht.com/6IV7BAcqjvjlbtYN27Dbh8-Khc5fEhJJOHxUYG7omxUoW_q8WDwqAeHvCWNwO7bTDg=h900');
  background-size: cover;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blur-bg">
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This
    <br>is
    <br>a
    <br>sample
    <br>of
    <br>background
    <br>image
    <br>blurring
  </div>
</div>
```