# Is it possible to blend repeated background images?

Tags: css, background-image

Is it possible to blend the iterations of a *single* `background-image` when `background-repeat` is set to `repeat` like so:

[image]

Solutions using javascript are also welcome.

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's quite unclear what you wish for. Maybe showing what you currently have will help understand better. Do you want something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147915/only-blur-repeated-image-in-background/44149099#44149099 but with blend-mode rather than filters?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-repeaty is this you looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need 2 images for this.

1. one that tiles seamlessly

[image]

2. and the starting top image which doesn't tile.

[image]

Your element will use the tileable one as its background. The background position Y should be the height of the non-tileable one.

You can then add a pseudo element `::before` on top of your element positioned to the top which has the background of your non-tileable image.

```css
div
{
  position: relative;
  width: 813px;
  height: 2000px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/joeNpq8.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: 0 682px;
}

div::before
{
  content: '';
  width: 813px;
  height: 682px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEovt.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```